# How to pass enum as method parameter?

Tags: c#, enums

The task is to write a simple method that can sort int array (in ascending or descending order - should be set as enum type parameter of this method). I have written the method itself and enum, but I have no idea how to set enum as method parameter:(

Would be great to get any help from you, guys, cause I am completely new to coding.

```
class Program
{

    public enum options
    {
        UpSortOption,
        DownSortOption
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 8, 0, 2, 16 };
    }

    static void orderArray(int [] array, options op)
    {
        switch(op)
        {
            case options.UpSortOption:
                Array.Sort(array);
                foreach (int number in array)
                {
                    Console.Write(number + " ");
                }
                break;

            case options.DownSortOption:
                Array.Sort(array);
                Array.Reverse(array);
                foreach (int number in array)
                {
                    Console.Write(number + " ");
                }
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `orderArray(arr, options.UpSortOption)` or you can pass `options.DownSortOption`. Enum values are retrieved via enum type name. Note that by convention type names should be in *PascalCase*. I would recommend you to use name like `SortDirection` and enum members `Up` and `Down` (or `Ascending` and `Descending`)

Comment: Visual studio supports you, just enter `orderArray`, add your array as first parameter and wait until vs-intellisense shows you the available `options` values as second argument.

Comment: The method is perfectly fine. What exactly the issue are you facing during method call?

Comment: Thank you, guys. I just did not know that enum values should be got via enum type. Now I know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the method looks fine, Now you wanted to call this method by passing the first parameter of type integer array and the second parameter of type `options` for that you can use the following code:

```
orderArray(arr,options.UpSortOption);
```

Or else you can declare a variable of type `options` and pass that variable, the change you have to make for that case will be:

```
options optionsVariable = options.DownSortOption;
orderArray(arr,optionsVariable);
```

Comment: Thank you for another option to set enum as parameter

Comment: @anna: Happy to help you always, You can mark the answer as accepted if it  helps you to solve the issue as well as helps to learn something

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a step back to see if it helps your understanding.

If you have a method that takes a string and an int like this

```
string MyMethod(string str, int num)
{
    // Do something
}
```

You'd use it like this

```
string rslt = MyMethod("Hello", 123);
```

What you've got here is something that takes in some stuff, does something to it, and gives you something in return. In this case `MyMethod` takes a `string` and an `int`, does something with them and returns a `string` which you then call `rslt`.

Your example follows the same basic pattern so you need to take your method - `orderArray` and give it the two things it wants - an int array and an option like this

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 8, 0, 2, 16 };

orderArray(arr, options.UpSortOption);
```

Alternatively, you could create an options much like you'd create a string and then call your method like this

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 8, 0, 2, 16 };
options myOption = options.UpSortOption;

orderArray(arr, myOption);
```

To fully illustrate the point that an enum as a parameter isn't any different from say a string you could modify your method like this

```
static void orderArray(int[] array, string op)
{
    if (op == "UpSortOption")
    {
        Array.Sort(array);
        foreach (int number in array)
        {
            Console.Write(number + " ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Array.Sort(array);
        Array.Reverse(array);
        foreach (int number in array)
        {
            Console.Write(number + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 8, 0, 2, 16 };
string myOption = "UpSortOption";

orderArray(arr, myOption);
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass it as a parameter

```
orderArray(int [] array, typeof(options)){
    //Beep bap boop
}
```

Hope this aids you.

Comment: That's not what anna is asking for.

Comment: "How to set enum as method parameter?" That is the question is it not?

Comment: Have you read the question or just the title? An enum value is needed, not the type.

Comment: I am trying to give advice to her way of solving the problem. Not giving her a different way that works for me. If she wishes to pursue this problem her way with regards to parsing enum as a parameter then i will give my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Exactly that's how you set up Enum as a method parameter.

To call this method use:

```
orderArray(arr, options.UpSortOption);
```

You can also assign enum value to a variable and use this to call a method:

```
options sortOpt = options.UpSortOption;
orderArray(arr, sortOpt);
```

You can also cast integer to an enum:

```
orderArray(arr, (options)0);

OR

int opt = 0;
orderArray(arr, (options)opt);
```

Remembering, that if not specified otherwise, first element is 0, second is 1 and so on.

By the way, you should rather use *PascalCase* to name an enum type, like:

```
public enum Options
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know one more way to get enum via its value